# My method is not passing my JUnit Test Case

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I have code for a circular array queue, the code has lots of comments explaining the workings.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CircularArrayQueue implements MyQueue{

    private int front, rear, count;
    private int[] queue;
    private int capacity = 1000; 

    public CircularArrayQueue() {
          front = rear = count = 0; 
          queue = (int[]) (new int[capacity]);  //creates an integer array of the default capacity
    }


    public void enqueue(int in) {

        if (noItems() == queue.length) //if array is full double capacity
             expandCapacity();

          queue[rear] = in; //add the integer to the rear of the array

          rear = (rear+1) % queue.length; //sets the rear to the last element in array

          count++;

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public int dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException {

        if (isEmpty()) //if trying to dequeue from empty array throw exception
             throw new NoSuchElementException ("Add to the queue");

          int result = queue[front];
          queue[front] = (Integer) null;   //leaves the previous front before dequeue empty

          front = (front + 1) % queue.length; //sets new front

          count--; //count - 1

          return result;

    }


    public int noItems() {

        return count; //returns number of elements in array

    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return (count == 0);   //return true if array is empty

    }


    public int getCapacityLeft() {

        return (capacity - count);  //return space left in array

    }

    public void expandCapacity() {

        int[] increase = (int[])(new int[queue.length *2]); //doubles array length 

        for(int scan=0; scan < count; scan++)  //"scans" previous array into new array
        {
          increase[scan] = queue[front];
          front = (front + 1) % queue.length; //returns the remainder of the calculation
        }

        front = 0;     //reset front of queue to new front
        rear = count;   //rear = number of elements in array
        queue = increase;

      }

}
```

and here is the JUnit test case my code must pass

```
import java.util.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class CircularArrayQueueTest extends TestCase
{

    private void checkSize( int length, MyQueue queue )
    {
        assertEquals( "Queue has wrong number of elements", length,
                queue.noItems() );
        if( length == 0 )
            assertTrue( "Queue should be empty", queue.isEmpty() );
        else
            assertTrue( "Queue should not be empty", !queue.isEmpty() );
    }

    public void testSimple()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        checkSize( 0, queue );
        queue.enqueue( 3 );
        checkSize( 1, queue );
        try
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", 3, queue.dequeue() );
        } catch( NoSuchElementException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        checkSize( 0, queue );
    }

    public void testMultiInput()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
        {
            int r = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( 0, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r );
            checkSize( 1, queue );
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r, queue.dequeue() );
        }

    }

    public void testManyEnqueueDequeue()
    {
        CircularArrayQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        int cnt = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i )
        {
            if( Math.random() > 0.5 )
            {
                queue.enqueue( i );
                cnt++;
            } else
            {
                if( !queue.isEmpty() )
                {
                    queue.dequeue();
                    cnt--;
                }
            }
            assertEquals( "Correct number of items", cnt, queue.noItems() );
        }
    }

    public void testLargeQueue()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        int[] r = new int[ 1000 ];
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            r[ i ] = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( i, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r[ i ] );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r[ i ],
                    queue.dequeue() );
            checkSize( r.length - i - 1, queue );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            r[ i ] = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( i, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r[ i ] );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r[ i ],
                    queue.dequeue() );
            checkSize( r.length - i - 1, queue );
        }
    }

    public void testThrows()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        int[] r = new int[ 1000 ];
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            r[ i ] = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( i, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r[ i ] );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r[ i ],
                    queue.dequeue() );
            checkSize( r.length - i - 1, queue );
        }
        boolean throwsCorrectly = false;
        try
        {
            queue.dequeue();
        } catch( NoSuchElementException e )
        {
            throwsCorrectly = true;
        }
        assertTrue( "Throws when dequeuing empty queue", throwsCorrectly );
    }


    public void testResize()
    {
        CircularArrayQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        assertTrue( "Initial capacity too large", queue.getCapacityLeft() <= 1024 );
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
        {
            queue.enqueue( i );
        }
        int currentCapacity = queue.getCapacityLeft();
        while( currentCapacity > 0 )
        {
            queue.enqueue( 9 );
            currentCapacity--;
            assertEquals( "Array size should not change", currentCapacity,
                    queue.getCapacityLeft() );
        }
        assertTrue( "Should have reached capacity", queue.getCapacityLeft() == 0 );
        queue.enqueue( 42 );
        assertTrue( "Should have resized array",
                currentCapacity < queue.getCapacityLeft() );
        currentCapacity = queue.getCapacityLeft();
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
        {
            queue.enqueue( i );
            currentCapacity--;
            assertEquals( "Resizing too often (inefficient)", currentCapacity,
                    queue.getCapacityLeft() );
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is `NullPointerException at CircularArrayQueue.dequeue at TestFailure.testManyEnqueueDequeue`. I assume I am getting this error from trying to dequeue an empty array but do not know how to alter my `dequeue` method to work around this. How come my `if(isEmpty())` statement in my `dequeue` method does not solve this (assuming this is the issue)? 
**Added Failure Trace Details**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at tutorialTwo.CircularArrayQueue.dequeue(CircularArrayQueue.java:41)
at tutorialTwo.TestFailure.testManyEnqueueDequeue(TestFailure.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Read and post the complete stack trace of the exception. Tell what line it refers to. Ignoring error messages is not a good strategy. What is this line supposed to do: `queue[front] = (Integer) null`? How could a primitive `int` be null?

Comment: That line basically replaces the dequeue'd elements index with nothing. For example if you enqueue 3 elements then dequeue, [0] should now be empty.

Comment: I thought this was weird when I was coding it but could not see an alternative way of doing it

Comment: an int, like all other primitive types, can't be null. Only references to objects can be null. An int can be 0, -1, or whatever. But you really shouldn't care what the value is. You can leave it ias it is, since it will be replaced by the next call to enqueue().

Comment: It will not be replaced by the next call, in a ring array earliest index is removed during dequeue and enqueue adds an element after the latest index if that makes sense, so in my example in my above comment if I were to then enqueue, I would be adding to index [3] and now index [1] [2] [3] contain values

Comment: After removing that line of code my program passes, thank you.

Comment: Using `Math.random()` in test code makes it non-deterministic, and so impossible to debug in a repeatable way. Replace all of your uses of `Math.random()` with calls to a `java.util.Random` instance with a fixed seed.